# Perl: Create a binary number and convert it into hex

Tags: perl, binary, hex

I want to create a binary number from the given user input.

Input - Array of number

Output - Binary number

A binary number should be created such that it has one on all the places which has been given as input.

In the given case input is 1, 3, and 7 so my binary no should be `1000101`, so it has 1's on 1, 3 and 7 places from left.

```
@x = [ 1, 3, 7 ];
$z = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
    foreach $elem ( @x ){
        if( $elem == $i ){
            join( "", $z, 1 );
        }
        else{
            join( "", $z, 0 );
       }
   }
}
print "Value of z: $z";
```

After execution, I am getting the value of z as 0.

I need to convert this binary to hexadecimal.

Is there some function which converts binary to hexadecimal?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to learn Perl. Please always `use strict` and `use warnings`. Those pragmas will help you find mistakes faster as Perl will complain about more things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ ]` creates an array and returns a reference to that array, so you are assigning a single scalar to (poorly named) `@x`.

You are also misusing `join`. Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! It would have caught this error.

Fixed:

```
my @bits = ( 1, 3, 7 );

my $num = 0;
$num |= 1 << $_ for @bits;
                                           #   76543210
printf("0b%b\n", $num);                    # 0b10001010
printf("0x%X\n", $num);                    # 0x8A
```

It seems that you want `0b1000101`, so we need to correct the indexes.

```
my @bits_plus_1 = ( 1, 3, 7 );

my $num = 0;
$num |= 1 << ( $_ - 1 ) for @bits_plus_1;
                                           #   6543210
printf("0b%b\n", $num);                    # 0b1000101
printf("0x%X\n", $num);                    # 0x45
```

Comment: Thanks alot. 
Can you tell me how can I store the hex value in a variable?
$hex_value = %X($num) will work??

Comment: I am trying to learn Perl. 
Can you please explain how this line works?
 $num |= 1 << ( $_ - 1 ) for @bits_plus_1;

Comment: Use `sprintf` instead of `printf` to grab the string instead of printing it.

Comment: `1 << ( $_ - 1 )` creates a number that has bit `$_ - 1` set. These numbers are "merged together" using bitwise-ORed.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

- `@x = [ 1, 3, 7 ];` is not an array of three integers. It's an array containing a single array reference. What you want is round brackets, not square brackets: `@x = ( 1, 3, 7 );`
- The string returned by `join` is not assigned to `$z`

---

But even then your code is buggy:

- it appends a bit at the *end* of `$z`, not the beginning
- there's a trailing zero that has no business being there.